# Как правильно прописывать путь к классу в CSS?

Tags: вёрстка, css

```
<div id="section">
    <div class="header-h1"></div>
    <ul id="menu" >
        <li class="item"></li>
        <li class="item"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Вариант №1

```
#section .header-h1 {...}
#section #menu .item {...}
```

Вариант №2

```
.header-h1 {...}
.item {...}
```

Какой вариант правильный и лучше? И в каком варианте страница будет быстрей загружаться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Во втором случае под ваше определение попадет любой элемент с установленным классом `"header-h1"` или `"item"`. В первом же случае стиль будет применяться только к `descendant'ам` элемента с установленным `id="section"`.

> Таким образом, второе правило `CSS` более общее и задает свойства для класса произвольных *элементов,* а первое - для класса произвольных *подэлементов* точно специфицированного элемента.

- Вообще говоря, второй подход считается более правильным, поскольку [способствует более строгой классификации и переиспользованию правил.](http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/)
- Рекомендую также неплохой [**референс**](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/) по теме селекторов, использующих одновременно классы и `id`.

Comment: Вы путаете:

     .header-h1 {...}

с этим

     .header h1 {...}

Первый случай в вопросе ТС эквивалентен второму, т.е это определение стилей к определенным классам. А вот во втором случае - это применение стиля к descendant-элементам класса header.

Comment: @Dexter Как это первый случай в вопросе эквивалентен второму? Под второй случай попадают любые элементы, которым прописали `class="item"`, а под второй - только их некоторое подмножество.

Comment: @Котик, ну как бы вам объяснить...понимаете, **"header-h1"** - это ИМЯ класса, а не **"класс + descendant-элемент"**, как вы утверждаете. Если продолжаете сомневаться, то гляньте в HTML-код ТС =)

Comment: @Dexter

- Да я прекрасно понимаю, что `header-h1` - это имя класса :)

- Давайте рассмотрим небольшой пример - пусть актуальная часть моего `HTML` документа состоит из одного `<div class="item>Hello</div>`. Теперь, на этот элемент будет распространяться второе правило, но не будет распространяться первое, следовательно, утверждение об *эквивалентности* неверно. Или я что-то упустил?

Comment: @Dexter, вы не поняли. Речь идет не о любых о дочерних элементах, а о дочерних элементах #section, у которых указан класс .header-h1. В ответе все верно, перечитайте еще раз.

Что касается кода ТС, то вы правы, разницы в объявлениях нет, и в первом и во втором случае стили применяться одинаково. Но поскольку это явно **часть** страницы, то можно допустить, что могут быть и другие элементы, для которых варианты будут не эквивалентны, о чем в ответе и написано.